# HTML form action giving error on apache

Tags: python, html, apache

I am a HTML and Apache newbie.

A part of my current project is to make a User Interface to take data from a user, and send it to a python program for processing.

I have started learning how to do so. I made a simple program, which prints "Hello firstname lastname" on the screen. I made another program which uses HTML form action to get the data to submit this.

The codes of the 2 programs are :
lets call this file second.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"

print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

To get data, say form.html :

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/second.py" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am using fedora. I do not have superuser privileges on the computer. I have another system (ubuntu) with an apache server running, where I have superuser privileges.

---

My problem is, when I run this on the apache server, second.py runs properly
http://***.*8.1.91/cgi-bin/second.py. 
gives an output : Hello NoneNone

http://*.*8.1.91/cgi-bin/second.py?first_name=Akhil&last_name=Kulkarni
gives an output : Hello Akhil Kulkarni

this is how it is intended to work.

If i run form.html (http://*.*8.1.91/cgi-bin/second_1.html) , I get an 500 Internal Server Error

I get this error in my errorlog:

```
[Wed Jun 12 15:40:07 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/second_1.html' failed
[Wed Jun 12 15:40:07 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] Premature end of script headers: second_1.html
```

I tried running it as a python program, I get the same 500 internal server error
Error log shows :

```
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28]   File "
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/second_1.py
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] ", line
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] 3
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28]
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28]
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] <form action="/cgi-vin/second.py"method="get">
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28]
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] ^
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] SyntaxError
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] :
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] invalid syntax
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28]
[Wed Jun 12 15:44:48 2013] [error] [client *.*8.5.28] Premature end of script headers: second_1.py
```

I tried adding print command in front of every line, like the first program. That also didn't work.

---

Next I run these 2 directly on my system, and not the apache server which is on a different IP. 
This time form.html runs perfectly, i get the boxes to enter data and submit option, but now second.py doesn't open on mozilla, everytime i try to open it, it open the program as a downloadable file.

So, form works on my desktop, not the apache server. Disply script does not work on my desktop, but works on the apache server.  If i make the from of my desktop to feed the data to the display script of the apache server, it works. How do i make the form work on the server, and the display script on my desktop?

I have spent half a day tying to find out what the problem is but in vain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is, when I run this on the apache server, second.py runs
>   properly http://*.*8.1.91/cgi-bin/second.py. gives an output : Hello
>   NoneNone

That's probably because you set the method of the form to get but it should be post.

> ...but now second.py doesn't open on mozilla, everytime i try to open
>   it, it open the program as a downloadable file.

The browser doesn't know what to do with a .py so it suggests you downoad it. The .py needs to be served and run by the webserver because it knows how to run and feed it with information.

Comment: Hello pypat, thank you for answering. Second.py is running properly on the apache server, i have no issues with it there. Since i didn't give it any input the first time, it shouwed NoneNone which is what i intended. The form won't open at all on the apache server(which is the first problem), just gives an error. Can you help me fix that?

As for the second problem( second.py getting downloaded instead of running on my desktopm) is there any way to tell firefox that I want to run it and not download it?

Comment: Okay, well then I missunderstood the question. If you wan't to run this on your desktop, you'll have to have some kind of webserver running there as well. A browser is not build to run .py like that. I haven't worked with cgi but I'm guessing that you have to return the html and not print it.